# open layer 3 shape dissapear

Tags: shapes, lines

I'm using Open Layer 3 with Open Street Maps.

I have got a list of specified locations and want to draw lines through each one of them to visualize azimuth and specify line crossing point on map.

To draw lines I'm using ol.styleRegularShape with 2 points and rotation that is calculated from given azimuth.

**The problem is that when zooming crossing point, my lines dissapears**. I assume it's happening because base location of each line is out of visible area.

I was trying to change renderer type but it did not help or maybe I did something wrong?

```
var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
source : source,
renderer : "WebGL"
})
```